# Treat with much tenderness

Tags: word-request

In russian we have a word "**приласкать**" - verb, which we can use to say, "**treat with much tenderness**". Usually with animals that means they'll start following you around. What is the English equivalent?

Comment: When you say "with too much tenderness", do you mean "in a way that is actually bad for them", or something else?  We sometimes use the phrase "killing them with kindness", like "I know you like giving your dog treats, but you are *killing him with kindness* - it's not good for him and he is getting fat."  But I'm not sure if that's exactly the meaning you're looking for.

Comment: @stangdon No, the opposite. **give too much kindness** - good thing.

Comment: A native Russian language speaker, I dare say that there's no indication of **excessive** tenderness in the meaning of the Russian verb "приласкать". The English definition you provide seems rather misleading. The nearest English equivalents for it, I believe, may be to caress, pet, fondle, or even to canoodle - depending on the context, of course. As for the animals, they are usually petted (stroked gently) or caressed. IMO

Comment: @Rompey I didn't say **excessove tenderness**, I said **too much tenderness** in a good way. But yeh, those may be helpful.

Comment: too much = excessive

Comment: @Tᴚoɯɐuo I disagree! Excessive means **way over the limit of too much** in a negative sense.

Comment: @Rompey There is. I'm speaking Russian 29 years.

Comment: @SovereignSun: You mean to say: "I've been speaking Russian for 29 years". And "excessive" and "too much" are indeed synonyms. Your sense that "too much" does not mean "excessive" is wrong.

Comment: @Tᴚoɯɐuo Yup, yup. English only for 25 years.

Comment: Let me throw "coddle", "pamper" and possibly "indulge" into the mix.

Comment: @Gary Botnovcan: Even more precise, perhaps, the doting pet-owner has been ***overindulgent**.*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

English might use different words depending on the details of the situation.  For example, my cat likes to curl up and sleep with me, in which case I say:

> I like to **snuggle/cuddle** with my cat.

In other situations I give him treats because he likes them, in which case others might say

> I **indulge** my cat

or

> I **spoil** my cat

At other times my cat likes to follow me from room to room, or rub himself against me when he wants attention.  In which case I might say:

> My cat is very **needy**.

or

> My cat **wants love**.

All of these may be implied by that single Russian word, but in English they are separate.

Answer (score 0):

If the Russian is specifically physical, meaning, "if you pet this animal it will follow you", I would go with "**caress**", as it implies physical contact that invites continued contact.

If it is more metaphorical, where you do something that appears kind but is actually not good for the recipient, I would suggest "**spoil**".  However, someone who is spoiled generally demands that the preferential treatment continue, and has little loyalty to the person spoiling them.  If the recipient is more made into an (unwanted) follower, perhaps "**indulge**".

Answer (score -1):

There is, in addition to @Kirt suggestions, the expression, "care killed the cat", meaning that doting on something (the cat) can have negative consequences.

Comment: I've never heard "care killed the cat" in all my years of reading and speaking English, it's listed as "archaic", and *care* was apparently used in the sense of "worry", so I don't think it fits at all.